# Apply custom ng-attr for every element ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular list of divs with button inside, for which I want to create an attribute with a constant value (for now, testing)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button type="button" data-ng-attr-selected="{{ 'selected' }}">Test</button>
</div>
```

So I expect every button element to have an attribute `selected="selected"`, but it's not the case. Why?

Comment: @Blackhole no, I meant button to have an attribute, I will fix my question

Comment: The `selected` attribute can't be defined that way, apparently.

Comment: @Blackhole is it a keyword issue? I can try changing it if iit work, will test it now

Comment: @Blackhole yes, its a keyword issue, can you make it as an answer, I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, probably because that's a meaningful keyword, the `selected` attribute can't be defined using `ngAttr`. Your code works perfectly with an other attribute name:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button type="button" data-ng-attr-is-selected="{{ 'is-selected' }}">Test</button>
</div>
```

If your really want an attribute `selected`, you can use the [`ngSelected`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive, but be aware that your value will be converted to a boolean:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- Result: <button type="button" selected="selected">Test</button> -->
    <button type="button" ng-selected="'test'">Test</button>

    <!-- Result: <button type="button">Test</button> -->
    <button type="button" ng-selected="0">Test</button>
</div>
```